# How to solve this error in Swift2?

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:19:33: error: cannot find an initializer for type 'Int' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'
var languagesLearnedNum: Int? = Int(languagesLearned)
                                ^

```
var languagesLearned: String = "3"
var languagesLearnedNum: Int? = Int(languagesLearned)
if let num = languagesLearnedNum {
    println("It is a Number")
}else {
    println("It is not a Number")
}
```

Comment: Your source is Swift 1.x, but your question is tagged [swift2]. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: It is working fine with swift 2.0.

Comment: println is deprecated since Swift 2.0

Comment: @EICaptain `toInt()` works in Swift 1 only.

Comment: @harsh-vira You have to use Xcode 7 minimum for Swift 2 but you're currently using Xcode 6. You should upgrade.

Comment: @Harsh Vira, please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `languagesLearned.toInt()`. However, you're not using Swift 2.0 as if you were, you would be able to use `Int(languagesLearned)` but not `println()`.